# Is it a bad idea to redirect type to subtype URIs in REST?

Tags: rest

I have several entity types that are rather different, but can sometimes be used in a common way. As an example, consider these entities: `article`, `slideshow`, `calendar` -- all of them are different, but all can be considered to be an embeddable part of a page, a `widget`.

I need to design a set of API URIs. Obviously I can go with either `widgets/123`  or `articles/123`.

If I follow the advice from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883674/39068) in [How to model a RESTful API with inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880472/how-to-model-a-restful-api-with-inheritance), I would end up with `widgets/123`. However I do not think this answer reflects my situation.

For example, consider `widgets/123/photos`. This is specific for `slideshow` and does not make any sense for a `calendar` (and is not needed for an `article`). I much prefer `slideshows/123/photos` or `calendars/345/events`.

However there are still situations when you want to get all of those as a `widget` list, without caring much about individual types.

Would there be any problems if I provided a `widgets/` endpoint for the widget list, but redirected requests for `widgets/123` to `calendars/123` or `articles/123` using `308 Permanent Redirect`?

Comment: redirects have a cost; that may or may not matter in your case.

Comment: @seand I have considered that, but seems OK for my use cases.

Comment: If you have full control over both the server and client code I'd usually opt to keep it simple and not bother with extra complexity (like redirects).